# Enviar confirmação de envio de form para email com o nome da pessoa

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para enviar um email de confirmação para o usuário que preencheu um form com o nome dele. Por exemplo.. Obrigado 'fulano'.

Sendo que, a linha do codigo de envio do arquivo php é essa..

```
"<p><strong>Nome e Sobrenome: </strong>" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . "</p>"
```

Comment: Você pode o PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer No site tem toda a documentação e um exemplo bem completo.

Comment: Qual o problema em enviar 2 e-mails? 1 para o destinatário e outro de confirmação?